# Kill process running on port 80

Tags: linux, debian

This is the process I want to kill:

```
sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/MerkMod $ sudo netstat -tunap | grep :80
tcp6    0   0 :::80   :::*     LISTEN    20570/httpd
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are several ways to find which running process is using a port.

Using fuser it will give the PID(s) of the multiple instances associated with the listening port.

```
sudo apt-get install psmisc
sudo fuser 80/tcp

80/tcp:               1858  1867  1868  1869  1871
```

After finding out, you can either stop or kill the process(es).

You can also find the PIDs and more details using lsof

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:80

COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME  
nginx   1858     root    6u  IPv4   5043      0t0  TCP ruir.mxxx.com:http (LISTEN)  
nginx   1867 www-data    6u  IPv4   5043      0t0  TCP ruir.mxxx.com:http (LISTEN)  
nginx   1868 www-data    6u  IPv4   5043      0t0  TCP ruir.mxxx.com:http (LISTEN)  
nginx   1869 www-data    6u  IPv4   5043      0t0  TCP ruir.mxxx.com:http (LISTEN)  
nginx   1871 www-data    6u  IPv4   5043      0t0  TCP ruir.mxxx.com:http (LISTEN)
```

To limit to sockets that *listen* on port 80 (as opposed to clients that connect to port 80):

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen
```

To kill them automatically:

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:80 -s tcp:listen | sudo xargs kill
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that fuser also has the `-k` switch to kill all matching processes, and `-i` to kill interactively (prompting you for each one).

Answer (score 12):

Here is a oneliner that shows the command to run :

```
echo kill $(sudo netstat -anp | awk '/ LISTEN / {if($4 ~ ":80$") { gsub("/.*","",$7); print $7; exit } }')
```

Replace `echo` by `sudo` for the process to actually be killed.

Comment: Replace `echo` for `sudo`

Comment: This is the perfect answer we just have to replace our port number with `80`.

Answer (score 5):

Three options for listing open ports are offered in [jsh](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh)'s [`whatisonport`](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/master/code/shellscript/net/whatisonport.sh):

```
netstat -anp --numeric-ports | grep ":${PORT}\>.*:" 

fuser -v "${PORT}"/tcp

lsof -P -S 2 -i "tcp:${PORT}" | grep "\(:${PORT}->.*:\|:$PORT (LISTEN)$\)"
```

I prefer `netstat` because it is fast, concise, and can list ports opened by other users.  (Although it will still need superuser/user privileges to list the names and PIDs of such processes.)

### Outputs

```
$ netstat -anp --numeric-ports | grep ":80\>.*:" 
tcp6       0      0 :::80           :::*            LISTEN      1914/apache2    

$ fuser -v "80/tcp"
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
80/tcp:              root       1914 F.... apache2
                     www-data  12418 F.... apache2
...

$ lsof -P -S 2 -i "tcp:80" | grep "\(:80->.*:\|:80 (LISTEN)$\)"
apache2  1914     root    4u  IPv6   11920      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2 12418 www-data    4u  IPv6   11920      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
...
```

The use of `grep` in two cases is to match only the port on the local side, and skip open connections to a remote port 80.  (An alternative would be to use `-l` with `netstat`, or with `lsof` to use `-sTCP:LISTEN`, but I like the greps above because they will also catch *outgoing* connections *from* the given port, which may occasionally be of interest.)

With `lsof` we use `-P` to display `:80` instead of `:http` to make the grep possible.  The `-S 2` option forces `lsof` to complete in a timely manner.

### Killing the process

Assuming we want to use `netstat`, we could grab the PIDs like this:

```
$ netstat -anp --numeric-ports | grep ":80\>.*:" | grep -o "[0-9]*/" | sed 's+/$++'
1914
...
```

And we could even pass those PIDs to `kill`:

```
... | xargs -d '\n' kill -KILL
```

However there is often a potential for false positive when using regexps, so I would recommend just looking at the initial output of `netstat` and then manually deciding whether or not to run:

```
$ kill -KILL 1914
```

### See also

I have another script called [`listopenports`](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/jsh/blob/master/code/shellscript/sys/listopenports.sh) which may be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

You already found out which process to kill: it's process number `20570` and its binary has the name `httpd` as written at the end of the line of the output of `netstat`. You can kill it by number `kill 20570` or by name `killall httpd` but I wouldn't recommend to do it that way.

Ports lower than 1024 have a standardized use (normally), you can look up those and many others with `less /etc/services`. The entry for port 80 is even commented:

```
http            80/tcp          www             # WorldWideWeb HTTP
```

So it is most probably a webserver. The name you have is `httpd` and `man httpd` should give you the large hint that it is the Apache binary which fits. Apache is one of the big players, it has some comfortable management-programs available but you don't need them for a mere start/stop action.

You have Mint? With a normal desktop? Then look in the `Control Center` under `System` and click `Services`. You need to be admin to do anything there. Scroll down until you find something labeled "webserver" (I have lighttpd instead of Apache and don't know exactly how the Apache entry would look like) and uncheck it.

If you just want to stop it temporarily try, in the console

```
sudo service stop httpd
```

and start with `sudo service start httpd`. `service --status-all` returns a list of all services `service` knows about and can handle. A shortcut for a restart of a service (that is: stop and start it in that order) is `service --full-restart SERVICE` with `SERVICE` being the name of the service, e.g..: `httpd` in case of Apache.

Most of the programs you find with `netstat` can be handled in that way. Some cannot and some don't even have a man-page but those are rare.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do this. First check which process is using port 80 by [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat):

```
netstat -ntl | grep 80
```

Now you got the process name and kill the process with the [killall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) command:

```
killall -9 process name
```

Comment: What are the perils of using the 'killall' command?

Comment: -1 for `killall` without explanation or warning.

Comment: There are several problems with killall. Besides being able to bring to it´s knees a system in case of a problem, also it can kill multiples instances of a process that is not associated with the port. To top it all, the biggest problem of killall is that if someone in a Solaris box tries to use it, it kills all the running processes.